# PHP Codesign opcache.so macOS 12.6.2

Tags: php

I was getting the following errors in my error_log.log file after installing PHP using Homebrew:

```
Failed loading /usr/local/opt/php/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so:  dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so, 0x0009): tried: '/usr/local/opt/php/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so' (code signature in <A05141A4-1FD8-34B5-A5D5-DC2A7C1491B3> '/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.2.0/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so' not valid for use in process: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.), '/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.2.0/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so' (code signature in <A05141A4-1FD8-34B5-A5D5-DC2A7C1491B3> '/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.2.0/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so' not valid for use in process: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.)
```

I then codesigned the opcache.so file:

```
codesign --sign "myCert" --force --keychain ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db /usr/local/opt/php/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so
```

and update the http.conf file with the following line:

```
LoadModule php_module /usr/local/opt/php/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so "myCert"
```

and restarted Apache.

I'm now getting the following errors in the error_log.log file:

```
Failed loading /usr/local/opt/php/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so:  dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so, 0x0009): tried: '/usr/local/opt/php/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so' (code signature in <A05141A4-1FD8-34B5-A5D5-DC2A7C1491B3> '/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.2.0/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so' not valid for use in process: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.), '/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.2.0/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so' (code signature in <A05141A4-1FD8-34B5-A5D5-DC2A7C1491B3> '/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.2.0/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so' not valid for use in process: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.)
```

I didn't get any errors with the code signing - I had to code sign `libphp7.so` as well which doesn't report any issues here.

Comment: same issue here? Anyone can help?